# Materials peel off when rendered

Tags: rendering, materials

Why does the appearance change before and after rendering?
Even if I change the material, it will peeled off same place.

I'm a beginner so I don't know why...
Please confirm.

Before render

[image]

After render

[image]

Comment: It looks like you may have a duplicate mesh that doesnt have materials rendering. Turn off it's visibility in the render or delete it.

Comment: @Dontwalk, I think that should be posted as an answer. That seems to be the most likely answer.

Comment: I fixed it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you may have a duplicate mesh that doesn't have materials rendering. Turn off it's visibility in the render or delete it.